# Intellisense not working for absolute paths in vscode with vue cli 3 project, jsconfig gives error

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm having problems trying to make autocomplete to work with a vue cli 3.0 project with javascript for absolute paths starting with @. For now eslint with vue plugin doesn't give any errors about import, so it is fine.

But setting up jsconfig.json for the autocomplete gives the error

> File [path to folder]/node_modules/smart-buffer/typings/index not found. ts

And it's not working,
checking the folder, there is a file but it's index.d.ts
I have no idea what to do to solve this.

My jsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"],
            "~/*": ["src/*"]
        },
    }
}
```

specs:

- vue-cli-service: 3.5.1
- vscode: 1.32.3 (user setup)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Answer (score 2):

Try this configuration:

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  }
}`

For a better known:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases